# How to test a peer to peer application locally?

Tags: networking, p2p

I'm programming a P2P application from scratch and I'm wondering how it's possible to run several clients locally to be sure that every goes smooth including at the network layer.

Is possible without using something like lxc or docker?

I have not choosen whether it will work over UDP or TCP yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can just run them on different ports or assign multiple IPs to a machine or use 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [**Netkit**](http://wiki.netkit.org/index.php/Main_Page).
*Netkit* allows you to **create a virtual laboratory** with several peers on the same machine.